# LSTM Does Not Do Well On Second Test Data

Tags: python, tensorflow

During training my LSTM performs well (I use training, validation, and test dataset). And use my test dataset once at the end after training, and I get really good values. So I save the meta file and checkpoint.

Then, during inference, I load my checkpoint and meta file, initialize the weights (using sess.run(tf.initialize_variables())), but when I use a second test dataset (different from the dataset I used during training) my LSTM performance goes from 96% to 20%.

My second test dataset was recorded in similar conditions as my training, validation, and first test dataset, but it was recorded on a different day.

All my dataset was recorded using the same webcam, and with the same background in all images, so technically I should get similar performance in my first and second test set.

In shuffled my dataset during training.

I am using tensorflow 1.1.0

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Sounds like overfitting. One way to prevent this is to use the tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutLayer. You could also try different types of RNN cells, such as the tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino in fact, it was not over-fitting (mainly because during training I use train, validation, and test datasets...see answer below). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was reloading my checkpoint during inference, and somehow tensorflow would complain if I did not call the initializer after starting my session like this:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
lstm_sess.run(init)
```

Somehow that seems to randomly initialize my weights rather than reloading the last used weight values.

So what I did instead is freezing my graph as soon as I finish training, and now during inference I reload my graph, so I get the same performance as the performance I got with my test dataset during training. It's kinda weird. Maybe I am not saving/reloading my checkpoint correctly?